# TypeError: object is not a function - Javascript, ExtJS, Jasmine and TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, extjs, jasmine

I am new to this (really new to Jasmine testing, ExtJs, and JS), and I have to fix this bug/error. I am running some unit tests and I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
TypeError: object is not a function
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (...main/lib/ext/ext-4.2.0-gpl/ext-all-debug.js:5499:56),     <anonymous>:3:8)
at Object.Ext.ClassManager.instantiate (...main/lib/ext/ext-4.2.0-gpl/ext-all-debug.js:5471:53)
at Object.create (...main/lib/ext/ext-4.2.0-gpl/ext-all-debug.js:2110:39)
at Ext.define.urnSearchBasic (../../../../main/app/model/SecurityGatewayUrnSearchResponse.js:72:26)
at urnSearchBasic (...test/spec/model/SecurityGatewayUrnSearchResponseTest.js:68:27)
at null.<anonymous> (...test/spec/model/SecurityGatewayUrnSearchResponseTest.js:150:17)
at jasmine.Block.execute (...test/lib/jasmine/jasmine.js:1024:15)
at jasmine.Queue.next_ (...test/lib/jasmine/jasmine.js:2025:31)
at jasmine.Queue.start (...test/lib/jasmine/jasmine.js:1978:8)
at jasmine.Spec.execute (.../test/lib/jasmine/jasmine.js:2305:14)
timeout: timed out after 10000 msec waiting for passed === true
```

The code for the SecurityGatewanyUrnSeachResponse (posted only partial code from lines 61-84 ) is:

```
61 urnSearchBasic: function (basic, config) {
    config = Ext.apply({}, config);

    var proxy = Deft.ioc.Injector.resolve('securityGatewayUrnMultiSearchProxy'),
        urn = Ext.create('CAS.securityAdminUrnProv.model.Urn'),
        formWriter,
        createdProxy;
    urn.data.urn = basic;
    urn.data.pageNo = 0;
    urn.data.pageSize = this.configData.getUrnPageSize();

72  formWriter = Ext.create('CAS.securityAdminUrnProv.model.SearchFormWriter');
    formWriter.setUrn(urn.data);

    createdProxy = Ext.create(proxy.$className);
    createdProxy.url = createdProxy.url + '/basic';
    createdProxy.setApiUrl(createdProxy.url);
    createdProxy.headers = this.configData.getGatewayProxyHeaders();
    createdProxy.setWriter(formWriter);

    this.setProxy(createdProxy);

    this.save(config);
84 },
```

Line 72 is causing the problem (Ext.create(...SearchFormWriter).
The code for SearchFormWirter is listed below:

```
Ext.define('CAS.securityAdminUrnProv.model.i SearchFormWriter', {
    extend: "Ext.data.Writer",
    alias: 'writer.SearchFormWriter',
    inject: [ 'configData' ],
    allowSingle: true,
    config: {
        urn: {}
    },

    writeRecords: function (request, data) {
        var cache = [];
            request.rawData = JSON.stringify(this.getUrn(), function(key, value) {
                if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
                    if (cache.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
                          // Circular reference found, discard key
                        return;
                    }
                       // Store value in our collection
                        cache.push(value);
                }
                     return value;
            });
        cache = null; // Enable garbage collection
        return request;
    }
});
```

The writeRecords function was causing the "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON."
when the code was:

```
writeRecords: function (request, data) {
    request.rawData = JSON.stringify(this.getUrn());

    return request;
}
```

After changing it, as suggested by the internet, the "TypeError: object is not a function" keeps appearing. There are about 23 specs and 16 of the failing due to this error. If you guys could please help me fix this, that would be great.

Thank you so much! Sorry for the long post...

Answer (score 1):

Near as I can tell, your attempts to serialize the result of your this.getUrn() function is failing due to a circular object structure. This in turn is causing your your Ext object definition to fail, resulting in the object is not a function error.

### **Edit**

To address the circular structure of the Javascript object, one must examine it for characteristics similar to the following:

```
var a = {};
a.b = a;
```

JSON.stringify() cannot handle objects such as 'a' as its children refer to their parent at some point. The result of this.getUrn() likely returns a Javascript object wherein a child refers to the parent resulting in the error in question.

To correct this, one can remove the offending values or their properties in the object returned by your this.getUrn() function. If this.getUrn() is returning values from the server, then it may be more desirable to remove them server side instead depending on your use case.

Does this help?

Comment: thank you for your respond. I think you got the part where I changed the code mixed up. Before, I was getting the circular structure error due to the 'request.rawData = JSON.stringify(this.getUrn());'
code. Thus, in order to fixed that, I changed my code (to avoid the circular structure error) to the following 'request.rawData = JSON.stringify(this.getUrn(), function(key, value) {...'
This is now giving me the object is not a function error. Do you know (anyone really) how to fix the circular structure error caused by 
'request.rawData = JSON.stringify(this.getUrn());' ?

Comment: I did mix that up; I've edited my answer to address your questions. Please let me know if I can help further.

Comment: yes, it does help. However, I am unsure on how to remove the offending values from the server side. Any help? Thanks again for your kind response!

Comment: You're quite welcome, Tilak. You'll have to go to your server side method which constructs the object(s) being sent to the browser, examine their structure and adjust it accordingly.